# Why doesn't this work? PHP random bg image CSS. Laravel Slim Twig

Tags: php, css, laravel, twig

This is the classic code used for randomly selecting a background image on reloading the page. While this was working when I tested it originally, since using Laravel framework with slim and twig ... I don't know what needs to change ? At the moment it is not showing anything just a plain white background... :/

```
<?php 
$bg = array('http://www.imageurl1.jpg', 
            'http://www.imageurl2.jpg',
            'http://www.imageurl3.jpg');
$i = rand(0, count($bg)-1);
$selectedBg = "$bg[$i]";
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            body{padding-top: 40px;padding-bottom: 40px;
            background: url('<?php echo $selectedBg; ?>') no-repeat center center fixed;-webkit-background-size: cover;-moz-background-size: cover;-o-background-size: cover;background-size: cover;}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        ...
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: try `$selectedBg = $bg[$i];`

Comment: @twentylemon still not doing anything :(

Comment: Maybe your image src's are wrong? www.imageur.jpg looks weird.

Comment: @Jeemusu what twentylemon suggested didn't work. I don't know how to do that Controller thing..

Comment: Try debugging it. echo  `$selectedBg` and then `die();` just after you set it, does it return a value? If it does then the problem is somewhere else in your application. I would suggest turning on error reporting in php as a white background suggests an error with reporting turned off.

Comment: @twentylemon no I just changed those to make the problem clear. The real links definitely work

Comment: @Jeemusu nothing is output :/

Comment: Sounds like you have an error,  you need to enable error reporting. Try adding this to the top of your file. `ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);
ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(-1);`

Comment: @Jeemusu and still nothing is showing

Comment: If you remove the php code you added, does the html display as normal? Did it ever display?

Comment: It must be something to do with laravel since this code works by itself

Comment: @Jeemusu yes. I'm going to test a js solution to see if it's a problem with laravel or something that's different with my php this time

Comment: There is no problem with that code, it works fine. http://codepad.viper-7.com/nWcGb1

Answer (score 0):

I just copied and pasted your code into a new Laravel 5 project and it works.  I used these picture links:

```
$bg = array('http://i2.cdn.turner.com/nba/nba/dam/assets/150805103851-damian-lillard-brooklyn-nets-v-portland-trail-blazers.home-t6.jpeg',
        'http://i2.cdn.turner.com/nba/nba/dam/assets/150805092335-archie-goodwin-dallas-mavericks-v-phoenix-suns.home-t6.jpeg',
        'http://i2.cdn.turner.com/nba/nba/dam/assets/150805123124-klay-thompson-with-family-trayce-thompson-080515.home-t3.jpg');
```

Are you using Laravel 5?  Did you put your code into the "/resources/views/welcome.blade.php" file?  Did you first see a "Laravel 5" welcome screen displayed on your browser after installing Laravel before your tried altering the code?

[image: File location and code that works!]

and here is the result:

[image]

When I click "refresh" in the browser, the image changes.

So follow these steps:

1. Try a fresh install of Laravel 5 by running "composer create-project laravel/laravel p2"
2. Navigate to localhost/p2 (or your setup's equivalent) and make sure you see the welcome screen that literally says "Laravel 5" in large letters in your browser.  If you don't see this screen, the issue is something completely unrelated to your code.
3. Copy and paste your code into the "/resources/views/welcome" file as shown in the screenshot above, with working jpg links (like in my example).
4. Then navigate to localhost/p2 again, hit refresh, and see if you don't get the above result :)  If the image files you are referencing are extremely large, it may take more than a few seconds for them to load.

Comment: I just copied and pasted your code into a new Laravel 5 project and it works!  I used these links: (see above edited answer)

Comment: and I tried the same effect with jquery instead of php and it still doesn't work.. :/

Comment: Perhaps your troubles come from using Laravel "with slim and twig".  Try a fresh install of Laravel 5 by running "composer create-project laravel/laravel p2", and simply altering the "welcome" file as shown in the screenshot above.  Then navigate to localhost/p2 and see if you don't get the above result :)  If the image files you are referencing are extremely large, it may take more than a few seconds for them to load.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the problem with your code.

```
$selectedBg = "$bg[$i]";
```

Solution:

```
$selectedBg = $bg[$i];
```

Comment: No it isn't the problem.